# What to do after removing autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity in eviews?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, heteroscedasticity

I am empirically checking Fama & French three factors (market, SMB, HML - independent variables) model on a Viet Nam stock exchange. The dataset is daily stocks' return during almost 4 years. The stocks are grouped in six portfolios - each is dependent variable in each regression. I would like to test the validity of Fama & French three factor model in explaining excess return of portfolios. Below is regression output of one of the portfolios, with a really high t-statistics. A reviewer suggested me testing for autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity and multicollinearity.

After reading a lot of guidelines on internet, I used DW and White test, found autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity and removed them using [EViews](http://www.eviews.com). Did Eviews adjust its input data directly to remove autocorrelation and heteroscedascity? If yes, i can run regression on adjusted data the same way with data without autocorrelation and heteroscedasticity?

The question is naive i know, I'm totally a stranger to econometrics and Eviews.

Comment: What is the purpose of the analysis?

Comment: @chl: i edited the question for more details. thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Just use Newey West standard errors for the heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation - there's an option for this in EViews when you run OLS. This should be completely acceptable to the reviewer (however I suspect that this is actually your homework). For the multicollinearity look at the VIFs (variance inflation factors) to determine if there's a problem. A simple Google search will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: Where is the regression output?